# Curved little bar piece seems incredibly useful... what is it?

Tags: part-identification

[On this link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kosmassantosa/), there is a special recurring curved piece throughout the photos. It is light grey, can be held by a figure on both sides but not the middle, and looks a little like a paint-roller handle. 
[image]

[image]

What is it? I want, like, 30!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This piece is [12885 Minifig, Utensil Paint Roller Brush Handle](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=12885&idColor=11).

[image]