# Part identification - (handle crank?)

Tags: part-identification

Please help me identify this part. (Both pictures are the same piece, just in different angles)

Reverse image search does not help unfortunately.

[image: unknown part]

[image: unknown part]

P.s.: Please excuse the unprofessional title, I don't know too much about part names- but I want to build something for a Lego fan I love :)

Comment: Related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7654/curved-little-bar-piece-seems-incredibly-useful-what-is-it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bricklink calls this piece [Minifigure, Utensil Paint Roller Brush Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=12885&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Paint%20Roller%20Brush%20Handle&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C). And its "part number" is 12885 or 34076.

Comment: Thank you so much!